# Is it possible to combine LIKE conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station
WHERE
    city LIKE ('A%') OR
    city LIKE ('E%') OR
    city LIKE ('I%') OR
    city LIKE ('O%') OR
    city LIKE ('U%');
```

Is it possible to combine the `LIKE` conditions to something less cumbersome ?
In `IN` % does not work therefore I can not use

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city IN ('A%', 'E%', 'I%', 'O%', 'U%')
```

I know that I can use

```
SELECT city FROM station WHERE LEFT(city,1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

but I an just curios about `LIKE` usage.

P.S. I am being studying SQL without being tied to any specific database management system.

Comment: In SQL dialects that support regular expressions and have something like `LIKE_REGEXP` it's sometimes possible to have a combined condition.  In your case it would've worked.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: @GMB  I am being studying SQL without being tied to any specific database management system.

Comment: @Kosh: regex functions are database-specific. Without a proper database tag, the answer you will get will, or will not, work on your actual database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

```
WHERE city REGEXP '^[aeiou]'
```

^     Beginning of string

[...] Any character listed between the square brackets

*Tried this on Mysql 5.7.26

Answer (score 1):

you can use REGEXP_LIKE. Sample code -

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(city,'^a|^e|^i|^o|^u','i');
```